# ASP.NET - Calendar control - Strike off dates with a custom strike

Tags: asp.net, calendar

I want to strike off all the dates before today in a calendar control with an overlapping, red color x in ASP.NET. I can strikethru using the normal font strikethrough using the DayRender event. I can add an image but that sits adjacent to the date. I want the x (image) to overlap the date

Is this possible? If so, please help me how to go about it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Use CSS,

1. Make the table cell position
   relative
2. Make the image position
   absolute, top & left: 0

**Update:**
The calendar control, like all ASP.NET control, outputs HTML. In this case it will output an HTML table, with a structure that looks *something* like this:

```
<table class="calendar_widget">
 <tr>
  <td>01</td>
  <td>02</td>
  <td>03</td>
  <td>04</td>
  <td>05</td>
  <td>06</td>
  <td>07</td>
 </tr>
 ....etc
```

The `<td>`, or table-cell as it's known, will contain the date and image you're inserting. You can use CSS to apply specific styles to the cell and image so that they are rendered differently.

My guess is your calendar's HTML with an image will look something like this:

```
<td><img src="x.gif" />01</td>
```

You can use a CSS stylesheet to apply the following styles:

```
table.calendar_widget td { 
  position: relative; 
}

table.calendar_widget td img { 
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

That's the basics of HTML - if this doesn't help I'd recommend tracking someone down familiar with front end development and getting their help.